# GIT rebase commits to top and bottom

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I have 3 branches. A, B and X

```
    A has a commit - commit A
    B has a commit - commit B
    X has a commit - commit X
```

I want to rebase A and B into X

```
     A branch's commit should be top of X branch's commit
     B branch's commit should be bottom of X branch's commit
```

final commit log should be like below

```
    commit A
    commit X
    commit B
```

Please explain the steps I can get the final result as above

Comment: What have you tried already? Create a branch `C` off the `B` branch, reorder the commits using interactive rebase, reset branches `B` and `X` to `C` and `C~1` respectively, delete the branch `C`, and that's done.

Comment: Do the branches have a common ancestor?

Comment: @fluffy I checked out to branch X, and run 'git rebase origin/B' then B's commit came to the bottom of X's commit.
Have any simple command like this to get A's commit to top of X's commit?

Comment: @j6t Yes, all branches from same main/master branch

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in this way with `git cherry-pick` instead of `git rebase`, assuming `main` is the common ancestor:

```
git checkout B
git cherry-pick main..X
git branch -f X
git cherry-pick main..A
git branch -f A
```

These works regardless of whether each branch contains only one commit or more than one commit. If there is only one commit in `X` or `A`, you can drop the `main..` part.